# MySQL Update Join Does not Affect ALL matching rows

Tags: mysql, join

I am attempting to do an UPDATE with a JOIN.  I have two tables:

- player_tracking has a list of all
  players that each user has added to
  tracking.
- users is the user list.    each user
  can set fsp_f to 1 or 0.

I want to update all rows in player_tracking for users who have fsp_f set to 1.  Here is my example code:

```
   UPDATE player_tracking AS pt 
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.name = pt.user 
      SET pt.newtome = pt.newtome - 1 
   WHERE pt.first = 'Brett' 
     AND pt.last = 'Gardner' 
     AND pt.sport = 'mlb' 
     AND u.fsp_f = 1
```

The problem is that there are **22 rows to update**, yet the UPDATE query **only affects 2**. Why?   Is my query wrong?

Here is the data found in player_tracking pertaining to "Brett" "Gardner" "mlb":
http://pastebin.com/kyf8SCy8

Comment: Please add sample data (not the entire dataset) that demonstrates the issue. Pick one row that should be updated in player_tracking but isn't and one row that is updated, along with any related rows from users.

Comment: @outis When looking at the affected rows, the second row that was updated had a space for the last name.  Instead of 'Gardner', it was 'Gardner '.  For some reason, this ruined the update for the rest of the users. I have no idea why that is.

There are other rows in player_tracking that have spaces as well, however after fixing that specific one, it fixed the query for the rest of the users.  Weird huh?

The only way to ensure EVERYONE gets updated, I need to use the following query:

  WHERE pt.first LIKE 'Brett%' 
  AND pt.last LIKE 'Gardner%'

Comment: That's why you don't use names for referential integrity, besides the fact that "John Smith" can be the same for two different people.  A surrogate/artificial primary key (IE: user_id INT) is a much better idea.

Comment: post some sample data and we might be able to figure out why.

Comment: Updated the post. Included link to the dataset. I'll post it in this comment as well: http://pastebin.com/kyf8SCy8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i believe that if you change the `LEFT JOIN` to `JOIN` you will see the exact rows that get updated since you are using a field form `users` in the `WHERE` part of the statement.

so basically you are trying to check if `u.fsp_f = 1` when there could be rows that do not join `users` and therefore will have the value as `NULL`.

Additionally it seems that the general layout of your query is not correct either, since you are joining on the `SET` statement and not in the `UPDATE` part - where you instructed which table to update

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I tried to use JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN and it still just affects 2 rows.

Comment: i would recommend an inner select instead of joining the tables in an `UPDATE`. something like `AND pt.id IN(SELECT user_id FROM users where fsp_f = 1)`

Comment: I attempted to do that query as well, no improvment.  i also added a SELECT statement should have grabbed ALL rows, but only grabbed 20.  Leaving out the 2 that the UPDATE affects.  I am going to do more testing to see whats up.....

Comment: @brant : please supply the structure and as much of the data in your DB so i can help you further

Comment: thanks for your help.  I actually figured it out and will use LIKE 'last%' to grab all records.  This is due to whitespace being included in some of the rows for last name.